# Right type of exception for access of array index which doesn't exist in memory?

Tags: c++, exception

I'm new to C++ exceptions, and i can't find the right type of exception for a bad memory access attempt.

Let's assume i allocated memory for 10 integers with this code:

```
int* intArray = new int[10];

for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++){
    intArray[i] = i+1;
}
```

And while trying to read it i made some logical mistake which will cause the program to access a memory i didn't allocate, for example:

```
for(int i = 0;i < 15;i++){
    cout << intArray[i] << endl;
}
```

What is the right type of exception to catch?

Thanks!

Comment: If you use a vector instead of an array, you can get the exact same effect but have it throw an exception as you describe. Do you want me to post an answer that describes how to do that, or does it have to be an array? Note that in modern C++, you'd be generally advised to avoid using arrays and new directly.

Comment: @NirFriedman about the first part i've solved it, but i do want to know about the second part, what do you mean by saying "using arrays and new directly" ?

Comment: Unless you are writing your own container, or in a handful of other cases, you shouldn't generally use new or arrays. Instead of an array, you should use a std::vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code

```
int* intArray = new int[10];
...    
for(int i = 0;i < 15;i++){
    cout << intArray[i] << endl;
}
```

does not throw an exception. This will lead to undefined behavior. Most likely, you just get the output of random data. When you create an array with `new` operator you get a sequence of elements with contiguous addresses. C++ does not have mechanisms to check the length of such arrays in runtime.

Comment: More precisely that should be undefined behaviour (UB). May be random data or a segmentation fault